# Multiple Invideo promotion using YouTube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I have to update multiple invideo promotion details for a particular channel.
My request is as follows:

```
var requestOptions={
part: 'invideoPromotion',   
onBehalfOfContentOwner: 'contentOwner',         
resource:{          
  id: channelId,

  invideoPromotion: {

    "defaultTiming": {
      "offsetMs": 2000,
      "type": "offsetFromStart"
    },

    "items": [
      {
        "promotedByContentOwner": true,
        "timing":
        {
            "offsetMs":4000,
            "duration" : 5000,
            "type":"offsetFromStart"
        },
        "id":{
            "videoId": videoid1,
            "type": "video"
        }
      },
      {
        "promotedByContentOwner": true,
        "timing":
        {
            "offsetMs":11000,
            "duration" : 5000,
            "type":"offsetFromStart"
        },
        "id":{
            "videoId": videoId2,
            "type": "video"
        }
      }
    ],
    "position": {
      "type": "corner",
      "cornerPosition": "topLeft"
    }
  }
}
};
console.log(requestOptions);
var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.update(requestOptions);
request.execute(function (response) {});
```

But when i try to execute this, I am getting error

```
0: {error:{code:500}, id:gapiRpc}
error: {code:500}
code: 500
id: "gapiRpc"
```

Even When I try to do this using the youtube api explorer 
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.update ,
I am getting Internal server Error.
Can somebody let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot promote more than one video. I also tried the same but getting an error "exceeded the number of promoted items". So you can only promote one video at a time.